# How do you compress a stream and upload it to Azure Blob Storage without writing to a file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-blob-storage, gzipstream

I have written a `Post` method in ASP.NET Core to compress the requests body and upload it to Azure Blob Storage. The method takes parameters as follows:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromHeader] string AssignmentId)
```

Various strings are then set, including fetching the connection string for the storage:

```
string fileName = $"{AssignmentId}.gz";
string compressedFilePath = Path.Combine(hostEnvironment.ContentRootPath, $"Test JSONs/{fileName}");
string connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING");
```

I initialize the `BlobClient`:

```
BlobClient blobClient = new BlobClient(connectionString, "assignments", fileName);
```

Then I create a file, and compress the body stream of the request using `GZipStream` to the file:

```
using (FileStream compressedFileStream = System.IO.File.Create(compressedFilePath))
{
    using GZipStream compressionStream = new GZipStream(compressedFileStream, CompressionMode.Compress);
    using Stream bodyStream = HttpContext.Request.Body;
    await bodyStream.CopyToAsync(compressionStream);
}
```

Finally I read the file I just wrote and upload using the `FileStream`:

```
using (FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(compressedFilePath))
{
    await blobClient.UploadAsync(fileStream);
}
```

This solution works, but I am concerned about the constant reading and writing of the file, in terms of speed. I attempted to use a `MemoryStream` passed into the `GZipStream`, however it ended up only uploading 10B files when the files should be 1KB+.

I appreciate any suggestions.

Here is the complete method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromHeader] string AssignmentId)
{
    string fileName = $"{AssignmentId}.gz";
    string compressedFilePath = Path.Combine(hostEnvironment.ContentRootPath, $"Test JSONs/{fileName}");
    string connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING");

    BlobClient blobClient = new BlobClient(connectionString, "assignments", fileName);
    
    using (FileStream compressedFileStream = System.IO.File.Create(compressedFilePath))
    {
        using GZipStream compressionStream = new GZipStream(compressedFileStream, CompressionMode.Compress);
        using Stream bodyStream = HttpContext.Request.Body;
        await bodyStream.CopyToAsync(compressionStream);
    }

    using (FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(compressedFilePath))
    {
        await blobClient.UploadAsync(fileStream);
    }
    
    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: aside from the BLOB storage upload, it's really a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10599596/compress-and-decompress-a-stream-with-compression-deflatestream

Comment: @MitchWheat The answer to that problem uses .Close() on the compression stream, but when I use that, it also closes the MemoryStream passed into the compression stream.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63623674/how-to-compress-files-to-zip-and-upload-to-azure-blob-storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually solved this by both leaving the compression stream open, and by resetting the position of the memory stream the compression stream is writing to (thanks to @MitchWheat !).

```
using MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream() ;
using (Stream bodyStream = HttpContext.Request.Body)
{
    using (GZipStream compressionStream = new GZipStream(memoryStream, 
    CompressionMode.Compress, true))
    {
        await bodyStream.CopyToAsync(compressionStream);
    }
}
memoryStream.Position = 0;

await blobClient.UploadAsync(memoryStream, overwrite: true);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Azure Storage library offers a push-based stream to upload content that works well with compression.

```cs
const int PageSize = 1024 * 1024; // 1 MB
using var sourceFile = new FileStream(file.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
using var destinationStream = await blobClient.OpenWriteAsync(overwrite: true, new() { BufferSize = PageSize }, cancellationToken);
using var compressedContent = new GZipStream(destinationStream, CompressionMode.Compress, leaveOpen: true);
await sourceFile.CopyToAsync(compressedContent, cancellationToken);
```